# How can I hide a CTabItem in a CTabFolder

Tags: java, swt, jface

I can't find any method for making a tab invisible or otherwise hidden in an SWT/JFace application --- I want a second tab to be available (or not) based on some other preferences set by the user.

It shouldn't be so hard to figure this out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way that I know of is to dispose the CTabItem for the tab you want to hide and then create a new CTabItem when you want to show it. Sort of,

```
 CTabFolder folder = new CTabFolder(parent, SWT.NONE);
 Label label = new Label(folder, SWT.NONE);
 label.setText("Hello");
 CTabItem item = new CTabItem(folder);
 item.setControl(label);
 // Hide it
 item.dipose();
 // show it again
 CTabItem item = new CTabItem(folder);
 item.setControl(label);
```

If you want to hide a tab in the middle you'll need to recreate all the tabs after the one you disposed.. It's probably easiest if you create a class that holds the control and a field that can be used to toggle the visibility. Then you can just dipose all the CTabItems and recreate iff the visibility field is true.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I appreciate it. I must admit I'm left wondering what the heck the SWT designers were thinking (or not) when they implemented this stuff. (sigh)

Comment: If somebody should face this problem 5 years later I have to add: there is no need to recreate all tabs after the created one. You can place the created tab into the right position using constructor [CTabItem(CTabFolder parent, int style, int index)](http://cs.nyu.edu/zilin/swt/API/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CTabItem.html)

Comment: I had to close all tabs programming and didn't find any method in `CTabFolder`. But your answer helped me. I actually wrote this code:

`for(CTabItem tabItem : cTabfolder.getItems()) { tabItem.dispose(); }`

vote up :D